# Android ArrayList getting clear automatically

Tags: android, arraylist

This is kind of weird issue i am having,

I am getting response from web service in this manner

```
"course": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "cou_name": "Engineering",
                    "L1": [
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "cou_name": "B.Tech",
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "cou_name": "M.Tech",
                        }]
                  },
                  { ...... } ]
```

I have created POJO class to handle this response in this way

```
public class FilterCourseDetail {

    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String COU_NAME = "cou_name";
    public static final String LEVEL_ONE = "L1";

    public int id;
    public String courseName;

    public ArrayList<FilterCourseDetail> mLevelOneArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


 public FilterCourseDetail(JSONObject object) {

        setId(object.optInt(ID));
        setCourseName(object.optString(COU_NAME));

try {
            JSONArray jsonLevelOneArray = object.optJSONArray(LEVEL_ONE);
            if(jsonLevelOneArray != null){
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonLevelOneArray.length(); i++) {
                    mLevelOneArrayList.add(new FilterCourseDetail(jsonLevelOneArray.getJSONObject(i)));
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

//Normal getter setter

public ArrayList<FilterCourseDetail> getLevelOneArray() {
    return this.mLevelOneArrayList;
}    

}
```

And i am storing it in following manner

```
private ArrayList<FilterCourseDetail> mFilterCourseList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray jsonSearchFilterArray = jsonSearchFilterObject.getJSONArray("course");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonSearchFilterArray.length(); i++) {
                                mFilterCourseList.add(new FilterCourseDetail(jsonSearchFilterArray.getJSONObject(i)));
                            }
```

Retrieving it :

```
private ArrayList<FilterCourseDetail> mFilterLevelOneArray = new ArrayList<>();
mFilterLevelOneArray = mFilterCourseList.get(position).getLevelOneArray();
```

Problem :
When i check the size of `mFilterCourseList` for first time, it's fine,
but using it again by

```
mFilterLevelOneArray = mFilterCourseList.get(position).getLevelOneArray();
```

and checking the size, it returns 0, means it's automatically been cleared.

I don't understand this. also is this the proper way to handle Inner `JSONArray` ? please help me out when i am wrong

Comment: where are you retrieving it in same or in another activity

Comment: in same activity, i am using this data for populating Spinners,

Comment: getLevelOneArray post this method

Comment: @sam_0829 why not use gson to convert json to pojo's.

Comment: First debug your code. Second don't need to initialize `mFilterLevelOneArray`  because its returns itself so change private `ArrayList<FilterCourseDetail> mFilterLevelOneArray = mFilterCourseList.get(position).getLevelOneArray();`

Comment: @apk it's already been posted,

Comment: @PiyushGupta debugging isn't helping..

Comment: Can you post the whole class? I mean the class you retrieve the data.

Comment: same issue here as well